# Use image field in custom field type

Tags: entities, media

I'm trying to create a custom field type which has several elements, one of which is an image. Is it possible to use an image field type within this form somehow? Most of the resources I find tell me to use a `managed_file`, but it seems I have to manage my own file in this case? As in move it from temp to public storage, create `file_usage` instances, and such? I don't really want to do that if I don't have to :)

As an example, I'd like to have something like the following in my `hook_field_widget_form()`:

```
$element['iid'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Image',
    '#type'  => 'image',
);
```

I would also like to employ other features of the image field type, such as alt text and styles.

**Edit:** I should add that I've taken a look at the [field_collection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), however the client I am working for has specified that modules without a solid version (those tagged as `alpha`, `beta`, or `dev`) are not to be used.

**Edit 2:** Looks like there's no way of using custom field types within your own custom field type. I ended up doing the file management myself by taking a peek at how the Image module does it's file management. Unfortunatey this means that I'm not taking advantage of image styles, although it looks like I could potentially do that by hand as well.